# How to display VS code popup tooltip like Android Studio's?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

VS code popup tooltip displays [image: Android studio's popup tooltip is very easy to use]

Comment: It looks like it is rendered as Markdown in VSC, AFAIK there is no method of marking a comment to be rendered as literal text inside a markdown tooltip

Answer (score 0):

if you are in windows
`ctrl+k` + `ctrl+i` will open up quick documentation.

`ctrl+shift+space` will open parameter list.